# Can we add the ability to place multiple links in chat event schedules?

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks, events

The Space Exploration site has many [chat events](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9682/the-pod-bay?tab=schedule), all based on live broadcasts of events like launches, arrival of probes at mission targets, mission press conferences, major lectures, and so on.

Right now to find where to see or hear the broadcast, and to find out more about it, you google the name of the event or the entity behind it (NASA, SpaceX, Virgin Galactic) and hope you get what you are looking for on the first page or so of results. TildalWave posts links to these places in the chat room when the event is added to the schedule, but you have to know to check in there and they scroll off the page fairly quickly, so you often have to search for them. He also posts them  shortly before the event begins, but often you might want to check them before that, and if the room is busy those posts can be a bit hard to find. Sometimes the link is posted repeatedly to handle that.

It seems like it would be a minor matter to make it possible for the links needed to be part of the chat schedule page. Could this change be made now (or now-ish) instead of having to wait for the overhaul of chat?

Example: This is what the schedule page looks like now for the next event:

[image]

It would be much more useful if it looked like this, TildalWave made a quick mock-up. He says one field added to the scheduler would be all it takes to allow him to list the useful links:

[image]

With the second version, I can easily go and find out about The Space Show and also Robert Zubrin on the newsletter page listed, and if I am in a hurry because a live broadcast is about to begin and I *really* don't want to miss a launch when all the cool stuff is over in the first 2 minutes, there is one place that loads fast that has the link I need.

And it could be done thusly:

[image]

Comment: If it's an official-ish chat, is it something you could do in Meta? For example, have a community wiki question that shows the chat event schedule? I know this wouldn't directly address the chat issue, but a mod could sticky star a link to the events Meta log that is then kept up-to-date?

Comment: @Catija - so you go to the schedule page, and also open a Meta page? Would it be clear that what you want is on that page, and easy to find for people not familiar with the site? How do you alert everyone to the existence of that page?